# How to use multiple keywords search back end of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend, search

I have a product called:

Volvo XC70 Polar Navigation XS2

I would like to search in the back-end on

Volvo Polar

but it gives no result. I can't use multiple keywords. Is there anyway to make that possible?

Kind regards, Arjen

Comment: What is the main language of the shop? For German, there are some meaning-oriented search engines that can help here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158504)

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

No complete solution, but maybe a starting point:

Have a look at `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid::_addColumnFilterToCollection()` and `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid::_addColumnFilterToCollection()`. I gets the filter-name from the column, as well as the string to search for, and applies a filter to the current collection:
`$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);`

I assume you could look what's in `$condition`, maybe "equals [string]", and convert it to a condition that uses LIKE for each word you entered.